# Inf and Sup question

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Suppose $S', S ⊆ \Bbb R$ are two sets such that $S' ⊆ S$. Explain why $\inf(S') ≥ \inf(S)$ and $\sup(S') ≤ \sup(S)$.

What does $S'$ mean?

Comment: Is your question "What does S' mean?" ?

Comment: $S'$ is just a notation for a set.

Comment: $S'$ just means another set, not necessarily the same set as the one called $S$.  This is _not_ an instance of some operation $S\mapsto S'$ where that notation does something with ever set $S$ to transform it to another set.  It's just as if it had said "Suppose $S$ and $T$ are two subsets of $\mathbb R$ $\text{and}\,\ldots$ ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Here $S$ and $S'$ are just two subsets of $\Bbb R$. You could have called them $A$ and $B$, or $X$ and $Y$, or whatever.

Bear in mind that $S \subseteq S'$, and every lower (upper) bound for $S'$ is a lower (upper) bound for $S$. Try to translate that into $\inf$ and $\sup$.